# Flask SocketIO messages not emiting to room

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm implementing socketio in my flask project.
I'm not getting error but no messages show up on my page.

Python:

```
@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    room_id = '1_2'
    join_room(room_id)
    emit('message', {'username': data['sender'], 'message': 'joined the room'}, to=room_id)
```

The js code for this:

```
const socket = io();
socket.emit('join', { 'receiver': 'george123', 'sender': 'chris123'});


socket.on('message', data => {
    const message = `
      <div class="div-block-51">
      <div class="messager-name">
        <div class="div2">
          <div class="div-block-50">
            <div class="inchat-time-sender"></div>
            <div class="inchat-name-sender">${data.username}</div><img src="/static/images/new-moon.png" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 10px, 1vw" srcset="/static/images/new-moon-p-500.png 500w, /static/images/new-moon.png 512w" alt="" class="image-15">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message-other">
        <div class="div-block-52">
          <div class="chat-message-send">${data.message}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
    document.querySelector('#chat').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', message);
  });
});
```

For sending and receiving messages everything seems to be working fine. Code to test this:

```
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('Connected to server');
          socket.emit('sendMessage', 'Hello from client');
        });

        socket.on('receiveMessage', (msg) => {
          console.log(msg);
        });
```

What it returns:

```
Connected to server
chat:35 
{message: 'Hello from client'}
message
: 
"Hello from client"
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong here? Why arent the messages showing on my page?

....................

Comment: You may want to enable Socket.IO specific logging in the client and the server and see where those missing messages are getting lost. It's really not possible to tell what's going on from your code snippets.